# Displaying svg from servlet using css's background-image

Tags: java, html, css, servlets, svg

I have following servlet code snippet:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("ICON");
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
response.setContentType("image/svg+xml");
```

And css snippet:
`background-image: url(/IconData?type=get&iconId=6)`

The image is not shown.

If I set the servlet URL directly in browser, then the svg is shown correctly.
One thing I notice in Chrome network console is that image/svg+xml content type is not sent in response header when accessing the servlet.

Did I miss something?

I tested with this svg file saved into DB:
[usa.svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Blank_US_Map%2C_Mainland_with_no_States.svg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely too late to set the header once you've written data to the stream. You need to set the Content-Type header before you write data to the stream.

The [`setContentType` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-) says, in part:

> Sets the content type of the response being sent to the client, *if the response has not been committed yet*. [...] This method has no effect if called after the response has been committed.

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

paste into your html

```
    content:type="image/svg" inside <header> <img> or <svg> ie <svg    
    content:type="image/svg">
```